# how to send post request by curl to web services in php

Tags: php, web-services, api, curl

I need to fetch data from  myallocator.com. I have his api address api.myallocator.com,
but when I send my data to them, it failed. I wrote some code for that which is shown below. Basically that pms property management system site.By that you can manage your property with his api.

```
    $url = "http://api.myallocator.com/";

    $xmlRequestString='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GetProperties>
      <Auth>
        <UserId>"xxxxxxx"</UserId>
        <UserPassword>"xxxxx"</UserPassword>
        <VendorId>"xxxxxxx"</VendorId>
        <VendorPassword>"xxxxxxxx"</VendorPassword>
      </Auth>
    </GetProperties>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $xmlRequestString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What do you mean it failed? What happen?

Comment: @WizKid ..it returned .... Could not parse XML

Comment: According to the API documentation you need to send a parameter called xmlRequestString. What you name the variable in PHP will not effect what you send in the request. So set the option CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to `array('xmlRequestString' => $xmlRequestString)`

Comment: @ WizKid.. as you read the api documention...what should be the vendor id and password.. i m confused about that

Comment: The documentation say: "If you would like to use the myallocator.com API you need to request a vendor ID and password first. It will need to be submitted with every availability upload"

Answer (score 1):

Here Is the example of php curl with post try this

```
        <?php
        $ch = curl_init();            
        // set your site url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://testmysite.com/");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        // postvar1, postvar2 .. are the parameters to send with post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");          
        // receive server response ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);            
        curl_close ($ch);

        if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

        ?>
```